# Ruby on Rails and Devise: Restrict Sign In to a Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, location, devise

I am using Devise in my Rails 3 application for admin sign in. I am the only admin, so I would like to restrict the sign in location to my State, so that I can only sign in to the administration interface if I am in my state. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the SessionsController.

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_filter :check_location, :only => [:new, :create]

  private
  def check_location
    # There, you check the location of the ip address with for example GeoKit gem.
    # https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails
  end
end
```